# Retry Array.forEach fetch request when response body includes an error message

Tags: javascript, foreach, graphql, fetch

I have built a basic web app that retrieves invoice data from a local database and posts the data to Wave Accounting.

I have found that errors from the api are contained in the response body.

I am trying to figure out a solution to retry the request if the response body from the api contains errors. (It always returns 200 as the status).

I have tried other solutions I have found on stackexchange (passing in a limit parameter to the function) and retrying if the fetch request fails until the limit number is reached.
The logic & data all work fine - just occasionally an Internal Server error occurs on the api end and I need to figure out a way to handle this.

```
function postInvoicesToWave(data, limit = Number.MAX_VALUE) {
let query = `mutation ($input: InvoiceCreateInput!){invoiceCreate(input: $input){didSucceed inputErrors {code message path} invoice {id title invoiceNumber invoiceDate items {product {id name} description quantity price subtotal {value currency { symbol }} total { value currency { symbol } } taxes { amount { value } salesTax { id name} } } } } }`;
fetch('https://gql.waveapps.com/graphql/public', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer <access token>',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        query,
        variables: {
            input: {
                "businessId": `${data.businessId}`,
                "customerId": `${data.customerId}`,
                "status": "SAVED",
                "invoiceNumber": `${data.invoice}`,
                "poNumber": `${data.po}`,
                "invoiceDate": data.date,
                "currency": "EUR",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "description": `${data.description}`,
                        "quantity": 1,
                        "unitPrice": data.price,
                        "productId": `${data.productId}`,
                        "taxes": { "amount": 0, "salesTaxId": `${data.salesTaxId}`} //taxes normally get paid - this is just testing :)
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    })
}).then(r => r.json())
  .then(res => {
    if(res.hasOwnProperty("errors") && --limit){
      console.log(limit);  //console logs random numbers  6, 18, 5 for example on the last test
      return postInvoicesToWave(data, limit);  
    }  
    else {
       //update the database with posted success value
    }  
  });
}
```

This is where the function is called - after the data is fetched from the database:

```
.then(data => {  //this is returned from the db
  const waveButton = document.getElementById('waveButton');
  waveButton.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  data.forEach(postInvoicesToWave);  //I have tried data.forEach(postInvoicesToWave.bind(5)); I have also tried data.forEach(postInvoicesToWave, 5);        
  });
})
```

Basically what I am trying to achieve  is to pass a parameter to an array.forEach function, and use this paramter as the max number of retries if the api response body contains an error.

Please excuse the question wording and any syntax errors I may have included - I will edit the question if any suggestions are made

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly it seems odd to blindly retry the api call without knowing what the error is?

But the easiest way to pass a parameter to a function within the body of a `forEach`:

```
const retries = 3;
data.forEach((data) => postInvoicesToWave(data, retries));
```

Comment: I'm currently working with test data. I'm not getting back any malformed errors etc! The only error I recieve is an Internal Server Error, I intend to accommodate other errors in production. For now I am just trying to implement retrying the fetch request if any error is returned: https://developer.waveapps.com/hc/en-us/articles/360018571372-Errors